How to append a middleware in specific spider along with the ones set in settings.py?
There are certain middlewares enabled for all spiders in settings.py.
How to append another middleware for one specific spider, along with all the ones in settings.py?
Let say settings.py is:
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.CustomDownloaderMiddleware1': 543,
    'myproject.middlewares.CustomDownloaderMiddleware2': 544,
}

If I set that middleware via custom_settings in my spider, then all others set in settings.py are ignored.
I tried
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        settings = get_project_settings()

        # Get existing middlewares
        middlewares = settings.get('DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES', {})
        
        # Append or update your additional middleware
        middlewares['myproject.middlewares.MyAdditionalMiddleware'] = 550
    
        # Apply it to the spider's settings
        self.custom_settings = {
            'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': middlewares
        }
    
    def start_requests(self):
        # Spider logic here
        pass

and
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
    
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    
        # Get the global settings
        settings = crawler.settings
    
        # Get the existing middlewares
        middlewares = settings.get('DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES', {}).copy()
    
        # Append or update your additional middleware
            middlewares['myproject.middlewares.MyAdditionalMiddleware'] = 550
    
        # Update the spider's settings for this instance
        spider.custom_settings = {
            'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': middlewares
        }
    
        return spider
    
    def start_requests(self):
        # Spider logic here
        pass

But the MyAdditionalMiddleware is not activated in my spider.
Note
Above codes were generated by ChatGpt https://chatgpt.com/share/6710b8b3-eda8-800a-a63d-5a244501475b

If I understend correctly you want to have custom middleware for specific spider level.
Updating your example like this should extend the existign middlewares declared at settings.py
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'

    @classmethod
    def update_settings(cls, settings):
        super().update_settings(settings)
        existing_middlewares = settings.get('DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES', {}) # get existing middlewares
        existing_middlewares['myproject.middlewares.CustomDownloaderMiddleware2'] = 544  # set the custom middlewares
        settings.set('DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES', existing_middlewares, priority="spider")

Like this you will get the existing DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES which is a dict like object.
And like such we can assign new key-value pair like a regular dict.
priority parameter points that this settings should be applied only for the instance of this and only this spider. Allowing you to keep the default setting for the rest of the project in cases where you run multiple spiders simultaneously.
The current example will allow you to extend the existing settings and not overwriting them.

I have a similar problem with that. I have hundreds of spiders and most settings of them are the same, several are customized. Here is my solution.
First, make a spider_settings.py file:
project_name = 'xxx'
    
downloader_map = {  # you can list all your downloadmiddlewares here with a alias
    'json_check': (201, 'xy_spider.middlewares.MustJsonDecodeMiddleware'),
    'abuyun': (202, 'xy_spider.middlewares.AbuyunProxyMiddleware'),
    'charset_change': (203, 'xy_spider.middlewares.CharsetSwitchDownloaderMiddleware'),
}
pipeline_map = {  # 0-1000
    'print': (301, 'xy_spider.pipelines.printPipeline'),
    'merge': (1, 'xy_spider.pipelines.MergePagesPipelineForNews')
}
    
    
class CommonSettings:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = kwargs or {}
    
        _downloader_mids = {'xy_spider.middlewares.XySpiderDownloaderMiddleware': 200}
        for k, v in downloader_map.items():
            if k in kwargs and kwargs[k]:
                _downloader_mids[v[1]] = v[0]
    
        _pipeline = {  # here are the pipelines necessary for all spiders
            f'projects.{project_name}.pipelines.MySQLPipeline': 300,
            f'projects.{project_name}.pipelines.MysqlQueuePipeline': 901,
        }
        for k, v in pipeline_map.items():
            if k in kwargs and kwargs[k]:
                _pipeline[v[1]] = v[0]
    
        timeout = kwargs.get('timeout', kwargs.get('DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT'))
        self._settings = {
            'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
            'SCHEDULER': 'xy_spider.redis.expire_scheduler.ExpireScheduler',
            'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'xy_spider.redis.expire_dupefilter.ExpireDupeFilter',
            'DUPEFILTER_EXPIRE_DAYS': int(kwargs.get('expire', kwargs.get('DUPEFILTER_EXPIRE_DAYS', 7))),
            'SCHEDULER_PERSIST': True,
            'SCHEDULER_FLUSH_ON_START': bool(kwargs.get('get_all', True)),
            'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': int(kwargs.get('delay', kwargs.get('DOWNLOAD_DELAY', 1))),
            'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': int(kwargs.get('thread', kwargs.get('CONCURRENT_REQUESTS', 10))),
            "SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES": {
                    'xy_spider.middlewares.RandomParamFilterSpiderMiddleware': 200,
            },
            "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": _downloader_mids,
            'ITEM_PIPELINES': _pipeline,
        }
    
        if timeout is not None:
            self._settings['DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT'] = int(timeout) or 20
    
    def __call__(self):
        return self._settings

Second, you can now customize your settings easily by create an instance of CommonSettings() in your spider class like:
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    is_test = not on_server
    _settings = {
        'delay': 1,
        'json_check': 1,
        'timeout': 10,
        'thread': 1,
    }
    
    if is_test:
        _settings['print'] = 1
    else:
        _settings['get_all'] = 0
    
    custom_settings = CommonSettings(**_settings)()

